# Need real help on this module

Tags: theming

I'm really need a good documentation or some kind of HowTo for [Google Font](http://drupal.org/project/google_fonts) module,i installed it and i choosed my Google font and what after? i m asking if i need to do some manual css or php work or just some other configuration in the GUI .
Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the module page desription says development of this module has been stopped in favour of [@font-your-face](http://drupal.org/project/fontyourface)

[@font-your-face](http://drupal.org/project/fontyourface) is widely used now and has decent documentation, so you should use this one instead of Google font.

Module page description,

> IMPORTANT: I've decided to combine forces with @sreynen, the
>   maintainer of the magnificent @font-your-face module. That modules
>   does not only support Google Fonts, but also several other font
>   providers and combines all those fonts in a very user-friendly
>   interface. I will not improve the Google Fonts API module anymore. So
>   please switch your site to (the 7.x-2.x version of) @font-your-face in
>   favor of Google Fonts. Thanks ;)